# Have a memset issue in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I'm a newbie currently using c++/cli to wrap a few classes that i have used in my .lib file. And I am in dire need of using "memset" in my c++/cli. Anyone here knows how to use memset in c++/cli code?

The c++ code I'm trying to use in my c++/cli code:

```
memset(&DeviceInfo, 0, sizeof(FS_DEVICE_INFO));
```

Here's my c++/cli Code where I get the error when I try to use the same memset line from my c++ code:

```
bool newIFSWDevice::GetDeviceInfo(PFS_DEVICE_INFO pDevInfo)
{
IFSDevice* pDeviceWheel = nullptr;
FS_DEVICE_INFO DeviceInfo;
int x = 0;

while (nullptr != (pDeviceWheel = newFSDeviceEnumerator::EnumerateInstance(x++)))
{
    memset(&DeviceInfo, 0, sizeof(FS_DEVICE_INFO)); //error line
    pDeviceWheel->GetDeviceInfo(&DeviceInfo);
    if (0 == wcscmp(DeviceInfo.Name, FS_DEVICE_WHEEL_PORSCHE_NAME)
        break;
```

I tried using a for loop instead...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(FS_DEVICE_INFO); i++)
    FS_DEVICE_INFO[i] = 0;
```

But it still gives me an error "expression must have a constant value". Help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: When I try using the same code in my c++/cli project. It gives an error saying "identifier memset is undefined"

Comment: What is `FS_DEVICE_INFO`? Is it a plain C++ struct, or a .Net class? Also, which error message are you getting? Is it "expression must have a constant value" like you said in the question, or "identifier memset is undefined" like you said in the comment?

Comment: FYI, `DeviceInfo.Name = FS_DEVICE_WHEEL_PORSCHE_NAME` should (almost certainly) be using `==` instead of assignment.

Comment: Yes! FS_DEVICE_INFO is a C++ struct indeed. Not .Net

Comment: And the error I get is "identifier memset is undefined". But when I try to use the for loop code (like I've showed above, trying to avoid memset) I get the error "expression must have  constant value"

Comment: If you have not included the header file with `memset`, you need to include the header file with `memset`.

Comment: @crashmstr Could you help me with that? Do you know what header file I'll need to add in to my code to make `memset` work?

Comment: A very simple search of "msdn memset" gets you [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fdeehz6.aspx). This really should have been your first step when you got that error message.

Comment: @Ðаn I am trying to re-write my C++ code into C++/CLI (in a C++/CLI project) so I can export it as a dll I can use in a CSharp project. And while I was writing it down I realized there were a few exceptions where I had to change the code according to C++/CLI syntax. It just so happens that the code until now doesn't need exclusive C++/CLI features. But I am only a quarter way through!

Comment: The C++ program happens to use a wild mix of pointers (*) and changing them to .NET(^) and analysing how the whole program runs on the whole is what is occupying a lot of my time! @Ðаn You mean to say I could just "Copy paste" my code and it should run?!?

Comment: Adding a simple <string.h> to my headers helped guys. Thanks a ton! :D :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you're missing the header file `#include <string.h>`. See the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/).

---

It's also worth noting that your `for` loop to do the clearing has several problems:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(FS_DEVICE_INFO); i++)
    FS_DEVICE_INFO[i] = 0;
```

- `sizeof(FS_DEVICE_INFO)` gives you the size of that struct in bytes, but FS_DEVICE_INFO[i] indexes into an array of structs: `[1]` would be the second struct in the array, *not* the second byte! You would need to cast the pointer to `char` or something similar.
- `i <= sizeof(FS_DEVICE_INFO)`: The `<=` is incorrect. If the struct is 10 bytes large, you'd end up operating on bytes 0 through 10, which is 11 bytes total, stomping on whatever happened to be after the struct.
- `FS_DEVICE_INFO[i]`: `FS_DEVICE_INFO` is the name of the class, your local variable is `DeviceInfo`, so this should be `DeviceInfo[i]`. This is why you're getting the `expression must have a constant value` error.